# Conversion constructor called for move but not for copy

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, copy-constructor, coercion

Using this code :

```
template <class T> class Test {
    T _temp;

public:
    Test() {
        std::cout << "Test()" << std::endl;
    };

    template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> const &test) {
        std::cout << "template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> const &test)" << std::endl;
    };

    template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> &&test) {
        std::cout << "template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> &&test)" << std::endl;
    };

};
```

With this test code :

```
Test<int> testInt;
Test<float> testFloat(testInt);
Test<float> testFloat2(std::move(testInt));

std::cout << "----------" << std::endl;

Test<int> testInt2;
Test<int> testInt3(testInt2);
Test<int> testInt4(std::move(testInt2));
```

Produces this output :

```
Test()
template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> const &test)
template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> &&test)
----------
Test()
```

The default copy and move constructors are used instead conversion constructors when using the same types.

But if I add default copy constructor in the class :

```
Test(Test const &test) = default;
```

It produces this output :

```
Test()
template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> const &test)
template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> &&test)
----------
Test()
template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> &&test)
```

The move conversion constructor is called even with the same types, why ?

Is there a way to unify the copy and conversion constructor to avoid duplicating code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules to add implicitly generated (= compiler-generated) move constructors are pretty conservative: Only add one if it's safe. If a copy constructor has been *defined* by the user, the compiler cannot assume that adding some simple compiler-generated move constructor is still safe, so no move constructor will be added. <sub>Actually, it's enough to *declare* it to prevent the generation of the move constructor, IIRC to allow copy-only types.</sub>

Constructor templates are never considered neither as copy nor as move constructors, so they don't prevent the implicit generation of those.

Of course, if the move constructor is never declared, another constructor can be chosen by overload resolution instead. Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct loud
{
    loud() { std::cout << "default ctor\n"; }
    loud(loud const&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
    loud(loud&&) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
};

struct foo
{
    loud l;
};

struct bar
{
    loud l;
    bar() = default;
    bar(bar const&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    foo f0;
    foo f1(f0);
    foo f2(std::move(f0));

    std::cout << "--------------\n";

    bar b0;
    bar b1(b0);
    bar b2(std::move(b0));
}
```

Output:

```
default ctor
copy ctor
move ctor
--------------
default ctor
copy ctor
copy ctor
```

Here, `foo` will get implicitly declared default, copy and move constructors, whereas `bar` won't get an implicitly declared move constructor, since it has user-declared *copy constructor*.

---

In your second case, there's no implicitly-declared move constructor, therefore overload resolution for `Test<int> testInt4(std::move(testInt2))` prefers the constructor template to the copy constructor, since the former takes a reference that's less cv-qualified.

---

To reduce code duplication, you could delegate construction:

```
template <class T>
class Test {
    T _temp;

    struct tag {};

public:
    Test() {
        std::cout << "Test()" << std::endl;
    };

    Test(Test const& test)
        : Test(test, tag{})
    {}

    Test(Test&& test)
        : Test(std::move(test), tag{})
    {}

    template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> const &test, tag = {}) {
        std::cout << "template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> const &test)" << std::endl;
    };

    template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> &&test, tag = {}) {
        std::cout << "template <class T2> Test(Test<T2> &&test)" << std::endl;
    };

};
```

By the way, you can also reduce some boilerplate by using a perfectly forwarding constructor template instead of two constructor templates:

Using this trait:

```
template<class T>
struct is_Test : std::false_type {};
template<class T>
struct is_Test<Test<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

You can define:

```
    template <class T2,
              class = typename std::enable_if<is_Test<T2>::value>::type>
    Test(T2&& test, tag = {}) {
        std::cout << "template <class T2> Test(T2&& test)" << std::endl;
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to study the perfect forward trick, but I have another question, you said that the constructor template is called because the move constructor is not added by the compiler because there is a user-defined (declared) copy constructor. But if I delete the copy constructor (= delete instead of = default), there will be a compiler error, the constructor template will not be used, why ?

Comment: @Johnmph Hmm not sure what you mean. Explicitly "deleting" (by using `= delete`) a function actually means *this function is invalid, if someone tries to call it, raise an error (at compile time)*. It does not mean *this function does not exist*. So if you explicitly delete the copy constructor, it can still be chosen by overload resolution. If that happens, the compiler will complain. (And you can't "make the copy constructor disappear" like the move ctor.)

Comment: Thank you I understand now, I have a last question please, can you tell me if your solution with tag struct to allow delegate construction adds some overhead in compiled code or if it is only used by the compiler and no overhead is added ?

Comment: I can't give you any guarantees on that, but if you compile with optimizations, the compiler *should* be able to drop that `tag` parameter: It's unused, empty and the function is inline/defined in every Translation Unit.